# Understanding array manipulation pointers syntax in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struggle understanding a syntax of pointers, for example,
I have this code below:

```
void main(void)
{
  char arr[][10] = {"It's", "wide", "and", "wonderful"};
  printf("%c", (*arr)[3] - 1);
  printf("%c", *arr[2] + 3);
}
```

I have no clue why it prints 'r' and 'd' like what's the whole process, I would kindly like an explanation.

Comment: I think you're dereferencing a character, then adding/subtracting to its ASCII value, then printing it as a character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll break up the expressions `(*arr)[3] - 1` and `*arr[2] + 3` in order of precedence.

Expression `(*arr)[3] - 1`:

- `arr` → `{"It's", "wide", "and", "wonderful"}`
- `(*arr)` → `"It's"`
- `(*arr)[3]` → `'s'`
- `(*arr)[3] - 1` → `'r'`

Notice here two things: `*arr` is equivalent to `arr[0]`, and you can perform arithmetic on a `char`, operating on the numeric value representing the character.

Expression `*arr[2] + 3`:

- `arr` → `{"It's", "wide", "and", "wonderful"}`
- `arr[2]` → `"and"`
- `*arr[2]` → `'a'`
- `*arr[2] + 3` → `'d'`

The news here is that `arr[]` takes precedence over `*arr`, that is why the parenthesis is important in the first expression.

Answer (score 5):

This is obfuscation: code deliberately written to confuse.

`*arr` gives the first item (array) in your 2D array. At index 3 you find `'s'`. ASCII code for `'s'` - 1 = `'r'`.

In `*arr[2]`, the [] operator takes precedence, giving you the item at index 2 in your 2D array ("and"). `*` gives the contents of the first item (character) in that array, `'a'`. ASCII code for `'a'` + 3 = `'d'`.

(Please note that arithmetic on symbol table values is not portable code. Only the digits 0 to 9 are guaranteed by the C standard to be placed adjacently in the symbol table.)

Answer (score 2):

```
void main(void)
{
  char arr[][10] = {"It's", "wide", "and", "wonderful"};
  printf("%c", (*arr)[3] - 1); // arr[0][3] == the 4th char of the 1st string - 1 = s - 1 = r
  printf("%c", *arr[2] + 3); // arr[2][0] == the 1st char of the 3rd string + 3 = a + 3 = d
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in first case `(*arr)[3] - 1`

- (*arr) gives us pointer to the first element of array: "It's"
- (*arr)[3] gives us fourth element of "It's" which is: 's'
- subtracting 1 from 's' gives us 'r'

in second case `*arr[2]`:

- arr[2] gives us pointer to the third element of array: "and"
- *arr[2] gives us first character of "and" which is 'a'
- adding 3 to 'a' gives us 'd'

Answer (score 2):

First, let's note that `*arr[2]` is equivalent to `*( arr[2] )`

Secondly, keep in mind there is no difference between `*(a + i)` and `a[i]`.

Thirdly, if there's no difference between `*(a + i)` and `a[i]`, there's no difference between `*a` and `a[0]`.

So,

```
(*arr)[3]   ===   ( *( arr + 0 ) )[3]   ===   arr[0][3]
```

The above produces the fourth character of the first string.

```
*arr[2]   ===   *( arr[2] )   ===   *( arr[2] + 0 )   ===   arr[2][0]
```

The above produces the first character of the third string.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays used in expression are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements.

So if an array declared like this

```
char arr[4][10]
```

then this declaration you may rewrite like

```
char ( arr[4] )[10]
```

and in an expression the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element

```
char ( *p )[10]
```

So in this expression

```
(*arr)[3] - 1)
```

arr is converted to the type `char ( * )[10]`  and points to the first string stored in the array. Applying the operator `*` you get the first sub-array (first string) that has the type `char[10]`.

Applying the subscript operator you get the fourth character in the string that is equal to `'s'`. Now subtracting 1 you get the character `'r'`.

In the second expression

```
*arr[2] + 3
```

that can be equivalently rewritten like

```
*( arr[2] ) + 3
```

you at first get the third sub-array of the array that is the sub-array with the string "and"`. This sub-array has the type`char[10]`. Dereferencing the array designator (that is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element) you get the first character of the string that is`'a'`Adding to the character 3 you get the character`'d'`.

The difference between the expressions is that in the first case you are dereferecing the array designator getting pointer to the first element and then applying the subscript operator for one-dimensional character array. In the second case you are first applying the subscript operator again getting one-dimensional array and then dereferencing the array designator that is implicitly converted to pointer to its fir element.

You should understand that if you have an array like for example

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

then the expression `*s`is equivalent to `*( &s[0] )` that is to `s[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

For `(*arr)[3] - 1`:

- `arr` when treated like a pointer: the address of the first element. In this case, it is the address of "It's"
- `(*arr)`: dereferencing `arr`, aka "It's". And it's a `char*`
- `(*arr)[3]`: the 4th character of "It's". The type is `char`
- `(*arr)[3] - 1`: `char` can be used as a integer, so subtracting a `char` is subtracting its [ASCII code](https://www.ascii-code.com/). The value is `'r'`

For `*arr[2] + 3`:

- `arr[2]`: the 3rd element of `arr` (treated as an array), which is `"and"`. The type is `char*`
- `*arr[2]`: dereferencing `"and"`, so `'a'`
- `*arr[2] + 3`: again ASCII code, its value is `'d'`

Answer (score 2):

The expression `*arr[2]` is equivalent<sup>1),2)</sup> to `arr[2][0]` -

```
*arr[2] -> *(arr[2]) -> *((arr[2]) + 0) -> arr[2][0]
```

The expression `(*arr)[3]` is equivalent<sup>2)</sup> to `arr[0][3]` -

```
(*arr)[3] -> (*(arr + 0))[3] -> arr[0][3]
```

`arr[0][3]` represents 3<sup>rd</sup> character in first array which is `s` and `arr[2][0]` represents 0<sup>th</sup> character in third array which is `a`

The 2D array `arr`:

```
Array arr:
  [0] = {
    [0] = 'I'
    [1] = 't'
    [2] = '''
    [3] = 's'   ---> (*arr)[3], substrat 1 from s ==> r
    [4] = '\0'
    [5] = '\0'
    [6] = '\0'
    [7] = '\0'
    [8] = '\0'
    [9] = '\0'
  }
  [1] = {
    [0] = 'w'
    [1] = 'i'
    [2] = 'd'
    [3] = 'e'
    [4] = '\0'
    [5] = '\0'
    [6] = '\0'
    [7] = '\0'
    [8] = '\0'
    [9] = '\0'
  }
  [2] = {
    [0] = 'a' --> *arr[2], add 3 to a ===> d
    [1] = 'n'
    [2] = 'd'
    [3] = '\0'
    [4] = '\0'
    [5] = '\0'
    [6] = '\0'
    [7] = '\0'
    [8] = '\0'
    [9] = '\0'
  }
  [3] = {
    [0] = 'w'
    [1] = 'o'
    [2] = 'n'
    [3] = 'd'
    [4] = 'e'
    [5] = 'r'
    [6] = 'f'
    [7] = 'u'
    [8] = 'l'
    [9] = '\0'
  }
}
```

---

1) The precedence of `[]` operator is higher than unary `*` operator.

2) C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..